# Parse and Facebook Linker Error

Tags: ios, linker-errors

I am currently integrating Parse and Facebook into an iOS application I am making. I have followed all the steps on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started and have also included all of the libraries needed:
[image]

But for some reason I am still getting this error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am not sure why I am getting this. I first included Parse cleaned and built the project and everything succeeded. But then when I added the 3 Facebook frameworks ( FBSDKCoreKit.Framework, FBSDKLoginKit.Framework, FBSDKShareKit.Framework) from the SDK I downloaded from their website it kept giving me this error. I have also updated my .plist file. I saw other posts on this error but they were all outdated. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using cocoa pods in this project?

Comment: yes I am. My pod file includes platform :ios, '8.4' pod 'Parse' and pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be the whole error message, usually, it's more verbose. Which is...? libPods.a is in red, that generally is a bad sign for a file.

Comment: Do you know how to fix that? I have a lot of files that are red. Should I try reading them?

Comment: update the pods or i would recommend  to add Facebook-iOS-SDK manually(without  using pods).

Comment: I think I know what I did wrong. I am using cocoapods but I am also manually downloading the SDK and including the framework. When you do pod install it will include parse as well as the Facebook-iOS-SDK. I do not think I have to download the SDK and do it manually correct? The only thing I would have to do is update my .plist.

Comment: Thank you Piyush! That was my problem... I was doing it with pods and manually. Your comment helped me clear things up!

Comment: i hope you know that after installing pods you have to open *projectname.xcworkspace. dont open your xcode project directly.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that! This was my only problem I had... I was doing it through pod and manually.

Comment: Yup..... :) Thats the problem.

Comment: So now the problem is that PFFacebookUtils.h has moved into another Framework, ParseFacebookUtils. But when I add pod 'ParseFacebookUtils' in my Podfile and then do pod install I get this error:         [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `Facebook-iOS-SDK` required by `Podfile`
- `Facebook-iOS-SDK (= 4.1.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `Facebook-iOS-SDK (~> 3.9.0)` required by `ParseFacebookUtils (1.2.21)`    Can anyone tell me if pod 'ParseFacebookUtils' is the correct pod to add?